# How can I prove that the kernel of a linear transformation with a matrix M is a subset of a linear transformation with a matrix M^2?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let L be a linear transformation with a matrix M and K is a linear transformation with a matrix M^2.
I need to prove that `ker(L) ⊆ ker(K)`

Comment: Did you google for $\ker(M)\subseteq \ker(M^2)$?

Comment: When in doubt, go back to basic definitions. What does it mean for a vector to be in the kernel? Knowing that, what can you say about the value of $K$ on that vector? Finally, what’s the definition of a subset? Relate that to your answers to the other questions.

Comment: You’ve asked several questions today about pretty fundamental ideas that you’re being tested on in the exercises that you’re attempting. It seems to me that some review of the material that you’re supposed to have studied before working these exercises would be in order.